# Submit form to a directory (example.com/product/), form action=""?

Tags: php, forms, directory

I've tried `<form action="/product/" method="get">`, but it doesn't work.

Usually I would have a PHP file such as `search.php` in the same directory such that `<form action="search.php"`, but I'm implementing a different kind of search which needs to always send the request to the same place.

What I'm getting: (e.g. if I'm on page `example.com/product/foo`)

`example.com/product/foo?id={query}`;

What I want: `example.com/product/?id={query}`;

**Update:** Upon instpecting the elements, it seems like it's my `action=" product "`. Something's up with the slashes. I checked the source code, and it seems fine.

Comment: does /product/ have an index.php file in it? This is a literal folder in your site structure, right?

Comment: Yes, `/product/index.php`.

Comment: "but it does not work". What doesn't work about it? Page not found?

Comment: Updated my post. It's always appending to whatever page the form is on.

Comment: Yes you can use the relative path in the `action` attribute.

Comment: `action"/product/"` is missing a `=`, is that an error in your question or in your code?

Comment: Oops, nope I have valid html.

Comment: @meiryo try this `action="./index.php"`

Comment: Nope, nothing. I suspect its a mod rewrite issue.

Answer (score 1):

Got it to work after changing double quotes to single quotes... `<form action="/product/" method="get">`.

Comment: @Undo I'm answering my own question.

Comment: Whoops, sorry. This came through the LQP queue.

Answer (score 0):

Use full url in the action...

eg

```
<form action="http://example.com/product/" method="get">

...
```

Comment: This is not a good idea. You should always use relative URL paths.